# Filter multidimensional array without affecting the key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I am working on a custom PHP project, where I need to get a subset of a multidimensional array.

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011
            [1] => Allegany
            [2] => 55.4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012
            [1] => Albany
            [2] => 325.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011
            [1] => Bronx
            [2] => 11
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012
            [1] => Bronx
            [2] => 11
        )
)
```

I want to return an array in which **[0] => 2012**  is present, like the following

```
Array
(


    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012
            [1] => Albany
            [2] => 325.1
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012
            [1] => Bronx
            [2] => 11
        )
)
```

Comment: Ok, then you need to check all the items in the array and check whether you have a subitem with key 0 and value 2012. What's the deal?

Answer (score 2):

The [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function is written to allow you to select a subset of entries from an array according to a customisable criteria

```
$subset = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function($value) {
        return isset($value[0]) && $value[0] == 2012;
    }
);
```

or a more generic variant:

```
$searchColumn = 0;
$searchValue = 2012;

$subset = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function($value) use ($searchColumn, $searchValue) {
        return isset($value[$searchColumn]) && $value[$searchColumn] == $searchValue;
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

Variant to simplify searching for matches in different columns

```
$searchCriteria = [0 => 2012, 2 => 11];

$subset = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function($value) use ($searchCriteria) {
        return count($searchCriteria) == count(array_intersect_assoc($value, $searchCriteria));
    }
);
```

Comment: Tremendous answer :) BTW, just in case, the logic without using any functions: `foreach($arr as $key => $v) if($v[0] == 2012) $out[$key] = $v;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's working perfectly. But in case i have to filter two elements like  "[0] => 2012 and [2] => 11"

Comment: Then you'd modify the logic of the callback `return isset($value[0]) && $value[0] == 2012 && isset($value[2]) && $value[2] == 11;
`